# How can I convert a Union type into a tensor type?

Tags: python, tensorflow, union-types

I want to convert a tab-delimited text into a 2D tensor object so that I can feed the data into a CNN.

What is the proper way to do this?

I wrote the following:

```
from typing import List, Union, cast
import tensorflow as tf

CellType = Union[str, float, int, bool]
RowType = List[CellType]

# Mapping Python types to TensorFlow data types
TF_DATA_TYPES = {
    str: tf.string,
    float: tf.float32,
    int: tf.int32,
    bool: tf.bool
}

def convert_string_to_tensorflow_object(data_string):
    # Split the string into lines
    linesStringList1d: List[str] = data_string.strip().split('\n')

    # Split each line into columns
    dataStringList2d: List[List[str]] = []
    for line in linesStringList1d:
        rowItem: List[str] = line.split(' ')
        dataStringList2d.append(rowItem)

    # Convert the data to TensorFlow tensors
    listOfRows: List[RowType] = []
    for rowItem in dataStringList2d:
        oneRow: RowType = []
        for stringItem in rowItem:
            oneRow.append(cast(CellType, stringItem))
        listOfRows.append(oneRow)

    # Get the TensorFlow data type based on the Python type of CellType
    tf_data_type = TF_DATA_TYPES[type(CellType)]

    listOfRows = tf.constant(listOfRows, dtype=tf_data_type)

    # Create a TensorFlow dataset
    return listOfRows

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Example usage
    data_string: str = """
    1 ASN C  7.042   9.118  0.000 1 1 1 1  1  0
    2 LEU H  5.781   5.488  7.470 0 0 0 0  1  0
    3 THR H  5.399   5.166  6.452 0 0 0 0  0  0
    4 GLU H  5.373   4.852  6.069 0 0 0 0  1  0
    5 LEU H  5.423   5.164  6.197 0 0 0 0  2  0
    """

    tensorflow_dataset = convert_string_to_tensorflow_object(data_string)

    print(tensorflow_dataset)
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe C:/git/heca_v2~~2/src/cnn_lib/convert_string_to_tensorflow_object.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\git\heca_v2~~2\src\cnn_lib\convert_string_to_tensorflow_object.py", line 51, in <module>
    tensorflow_dataset = convert_string_to_tensorflow_object(data_string)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\git\heca_v2~~2\src\cnn_lib\convert_string_to_tensorflow_object.py", line 34, in convert_string_to_tensorflow_object
    tf_data_type = TF_DATA_TYPES[type(CellType)]
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: <class 'typing._UnionGenericAlias'>

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can I resolve the error?

Comment: The error message looks like you should be using a string, not a type, as the subscript.

Comment: what would be your expected end result?

Comment: @AloneTogether, A 2D Tensor.

Comment: Ah ok thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is because `type(CellType)` does not return one of the keys in your `TF_DATA_TYPES` dictionary. `CellType` is a [union type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-union), and calling `type()` on it will *not* return `str`, `float`, `int`, or `bool`.

Instead of trying to find the data type from `CellType`, inspect the actual data items and convert them to the appropriate data type.

> > What would be your expected end result?
>
> A 2D Tensor.

You could also convert the list of rows into a TensorFlow tensor.
That would require all data to be of the same data type, so you may need to decide on a common data type that can represent all your data without loss of information.

Since a [TensorFlow CNN (Convolutional Neural Network)](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/cnn) typically work with numeric data, try `float`.

Finally, Your code attempts to split each line by a space (`' '`), but you mentioned that your data is tab-delimited. You should change `line.split(' ')` to `line.split('\t')`.

```py
from typing import List
import tensorflow as tf

def convert_string_to_tensorflow_object(data_string):
    # Split the string into lines
    linesStringList1d: List[str] = data_string.strip().split('\n')

    # Split each line into columns
    dataStringList2d: List[List[str]] = [line.split('\t') for line in linesStringList1d]

    # Convert the string items to float, as CNNs typically work with numeric data
    dataFloatList2d: List[List[float]] = [[float(item) for item in row] for row in dataStringList2d]

    # Convert the data to a TensorFlow tensor
    tensor = tf.constant(dataFloatList2d, dtype=tf.float32)

    return tensor

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Example usage
    data_string: str = """
    1\tASN\tC\t7.042\t9.118\t0.000\t1\t1\t1\t1\t1\t0
    2\tLEU\tH\t5.781\t5.488\t7.470\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1\t0
    3\tTHR\tH\t5.399\t5.166\t6.452\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0
    4\tGLU\tH\t5.373\t4.852\t6.069\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1\t0
    5\tLEU\tH\t5.423\t5.164\t6.197\t0\t0\t0\t0\t2\t0
    """

    tensorflow_tensor = convert_string_to_tensorflow_object(data_string)
    print(tensorflow_tensor)
```

That way, you split each line by tab characters, convert the string representations of numbers to `float` (assuming your CNN can work with float data), and create a [`tf.Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor) from the 2D list of floats.

```
| 2D List of mixed dtypes (as per CellType) |
\------+------------------------------------/
       |
       | Convert all elements to float
       v
| 2D List of float                          |
\------+------------------------------------/
       |
       | Convert to TensorFlow Tensor
       v
| 2D TensorFlow Tensor                      |
\------+------------------------------------/
```